# Jenkins Slave Agent Proxy 407

Tags: jenkins, proxy, jenkins-agent, webproxy, http-status-code-407

I have a Jenkins installation on Windows Server which consists auf one master node and two build nodes. Jenkins master as well as the build nodes are running as windows service under a domain service user.

For test purpose I created a pipeline where a visual studio project is retrieved from git repo in the domain, after that the project is compiled and tested
via msbuild and vs.test.

The test itself includes a webservice call to an IIS where a web service is running.

In Jenkins (Master) I have configured the proxy information (proxy, port, user, password)

On the master node the pipeline works fine no errors.
On the build nodes I get an 407 proxy authentication when it comes to the web service call in the tests.

I think I already tried a lot (Windows Proxy Configuration on the build nodes, Java arguments Dhttp.Proxy,...)
Nothing solved that issued and now I am puzzled and have no further ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your proxy server is not open it requires your credential. 
you need to pass like 
`user:password@proxyserver:proxyport` or you can use some third party service like [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I will try this soon. But I ask myself why does it work on the master node And not on the build nodes.